# Ошибка при вызове метода WallpaperManager

Tags: android

С переходом приложения с `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'` на `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'` у меня на эмуляторе с API 28 приложение закрывается с фатальной ошибкой при вызове метода: `WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);` Если поменять в Gradle обратно `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'` на 26+ то ошибки не возникает

Как нужно изменить код для запуска на устройствах с Android 9 ?
LogCat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.admin.xgame, PID: 23428
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.admin.xgame/com.admin.xgame.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: read wallpaper: Neither user 10069 nor current process has android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3784)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3816)
at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: read wallpaper: Neither user 10069 nor current process has android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1942)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1910)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1860)
at android.app.IWallpaperManager$Stub$Proxy.getWallpaper(IWallpaperManager.java:495)
at android.app.WallpaperManager$Globals.getCurrentWallpaperLocked(WallpaperManager.java:457)
at android.app.WallpaperManager$Globals.peekWallpaperBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:411)
at android.app.WallpaperManager$Globals.peekWallpaperBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:388)
at android.app.WallpaperManager.getFastDrawable(WallpaperManager.java:795)
**at com.admin.xgame.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:2479)**
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1412)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7292)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3776)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3816) 
at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1812)
at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1840)
at com.android.server.wallpaper.WallpaperManagerService.enforceCallingOrSelfPermissionAndAppOp(WallpaperManagerService.java:1800)
at com.android.server.wallpaper.WallpaperManagerService.getWallpaper(WallpaperManagerService.java:1818)
at android.app.IWallpaperManager$Stub.onTransact(IWallpaperManager.java:134)
```

Comment: А может хоть `logcat` покажите? Ничего же не понятно

Comment: он ссылается только на номер строки, где находится WallpaperManager wallpaperManager, если поменять обратно com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+' на 26+ то ошибки не возникает

Comment: 1) Уберите `*:28.+`  вместо + рекомендуется ставить стабильную версию 2) почитайте что пишет на эту тему `lint` - если есть проблемы с совместимостью версий [lint отчет](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint) должен помочь.

Comment: @Hellraiser, значит не правильно что-то вызывается. Без кода не понять. `MainActivity.java:2479` метод в котором находится эта строка покажите

Comment: добавьте разрешение android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз вы не предоставили ни файл манифеста, ни метод, в котором находится проблемная строка, могу только предположить.

С API 27 `WallpaperManager` требуется разрешение `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Соответственно нужно добавить строку в `Manifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

В методе перед тем как вызвать `WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this)`, нужно проверить что есть нужное разрешение:

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //Нет разрешения,запрашиваем
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
}
else {
   //Есть разрешения, выполняем действия.
}
```

Comment: понятно, спасибо